# Create and use parameters to visualize variables in Power BI service

Tags: database, import, parameters, report, mode

Can we change parameters value in Direct query mode in PBI service?
Problem description:

- I have 20,000 devices
- each of them has 20,000 records
  How to create a report where you would select a device from, for example, a table, and then only get its records on the chart?

Selecting another device would show its data.
Is it possible to use a parameter that is passed to query?